# Is there any performance gain while incrementing char pointer over accessing elements by index?

Tags: c

I'm in a process of refreshing my "C" knowledge. I get that Arrays *decay* to pointers and how that works. In string processing I keep running in to code that looks like this;

```
int count_spaces(const char *s)
{
    int count = 0;

    for(; *s != '\0'; s++){
        if(*s == ' '){
            count++;
        }
    }

return count;

}
```

What performance gain do I get out of my string processing code instead of writing my function as this?

```
int count_spaces(const char s[])
{
    int count = 0, i;

    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] == ' '){
            count++;
        }
    }
return count;

}
```

Is there an easy lexicon to go by for when to use  a pointer and when not to?

Comment: Did you try checking the asm version?

Comment: @ultrasounder you have a minor syntax error.  You need an extra single quote after \0 in the second code sample.

Comment: plus missing important bracketing!

Comment: @DylanKirkby what important bracketing?

Comment: @DylanKirkby even just proper formatting would work :)

Comment: @ultrasounder it helps readability if you bracket your for loops.  For example in your second excerpt, it is not immediately clear that the `return count` happens outside of both the if and for control structures.

Comment: @DylanKirkby actually I find that unnecessary bracketing hinders readabilty, but proper indention improves readability.

Comment: @Dylan Kirkby I agree.  The intention of the code is obfuscated by the lack of curly braces and coherent indentation.  Fixing these problems should improve readability.

Comment: you should change `cont char *s` to `const char *s`

Comment: The prototype for your second function could be the same as your first, namely `int count_spaces(const char *s)` and you could still access it with `s[i]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is compiler dependent.  Some compilers may offer a performance gain for one method or the other.

However, it may be useful to look at a specific example.  Using `gcc -S -O0`, the lowest optimized assembly output on my machine gives 3 **more** instructions for the first function than the second function.

But using the `-O3` flag they are optimized to identical assembly files.

Edit: also see bracketing that makes your code as readable and resistant to unlucky errors as possible :)

```
int count_spaces(const char s[]) {
    int count = 0, i;

    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(s[i] == ' ') {
            count ++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Edit:

To answer your question clearly: use whichever is most clear to you and whoever may read your code.  The performance boost you may get is negligible compared to the benefit of readability and clarity of intention.  Leave it to the compiler to squeeze this kind of performance out of your code

Comment: @dylanKirby thanks for the pointers to the compiler optimization flags. I pad the price for using a text editor to write my code snippet instead of using a proper Editor with formatting. Fixed now.

Comment: Agree with the comment about clarity.  If performance was absolutely critical, this function would be written without branching, and possibly vectorised with SIMD instructions.  That would only make sense if the input `s` was a very long string.